# Find top users who cumulatively have 75% of all points

Tags: oracle, rank

I am trying to find out the top users who cumulatively have 75% of all points.

Table is:

[image]

In this users list must the result should be users (dick, mary, jack and sam).

I try with (Oracle select..)

```
SELECT o.users, SUM (o.points)
  FROM (SELECT users,
               SUM (points),
               RANK () OVER (ORDER BY SUM (points) DESC) r
          FROM points_tbl) o;
```

--> error is:

> ORA-00904: "o"."points": invalid identifier

Answer (score 2):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/de2c50/17)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE points ( "user", points ) AS
SELECT 'joe',  10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'bill', 15 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'dick', 25 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'jack', 32 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'mary', 45 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'noe',  12 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'sam',  18 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT "user", points
FROM   (
  SELECT p.*,
         COALESCE( 
           SUM( points ) OVER (
             ORDER BY points DESC
             ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
           ),
           0
         ) / SUM( points ) OVER () AS pct
  FROM   points p
  ORDER BY points DESC
)
WHERE pct < .75
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/de2c50/17/0)**:

```
| user | POINTS |
|------|--------|
| mary |     45 |
| jack |     32 |
| dick |     25 |
|  sam |     18 |
```